# Java DB (Embedded) connection cannot find database

Tags: java, database, netbeans, derby, embedded-database

I am trying to create a connection using Java DB (Embedded), but I keep getting the error shown in the image below:

[image: Java DB Connection Error]

If it helps my Java DB Installation path is: `C:\Program Files (x86)\glassfish-3.1.2.2\javadb` and my database location is: `C:\Users\MyPC\.netbeans-derby`

I have tried specifying the file paths, I have watched YouTube tutorials and tried a few examples from Oracle and other sites, none of which help.

The properties (if it helps) for this database are:

[image: Java DB Properties]

I noticed that the driver class is `ClientDriver`, is it posible this could be playing a role in the problem?

How can I get the Java DB (Embedded) connection to work (or simply correct the problem)?

Comment: I'm confused: one screenshot shows the JDBC Connection URL as `jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/testdb`, but the other screenshot shows the JDBC Connection URL as `jdbc:derby:testdb`. Which is it?

Comment: Sorry, it is currently the `localhost:1527` because when I create databases on derby, that's how it sets it by default. I cannot change it from localhost as netbeans/derby insists that the database does not exist even though it does

Answer (score 0):

The root directory doesn't load, find the location on the Database, 
eg C:\Users\xxx.netbeans-derby\dataBaseName
copy it and paste it  as the database Java DB(Embedded) name. Your new JDBC URL: is now jdbc:derby:C:\Users\xxx.netbeans-derby\dataBaseName
Test the connection and the path should connect.
I think this is a bug in 8.1 and needs to be addressed, but this will work around it.